# Using `Array#[]` versus `find("...:nth-child(n)")`

Tags: ruby, capybara

When I want to pick up a certain node out of multiple nodes of the same type by its index, there are the following ways to do so:

```
some_table_node.find("tr:nth-child(3)").find("td:nth-child(5)")

some_table_node.all("tr")[2].all("td")[4]
```

Which way is better? Can you provide arguments with your preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` waits, `all` does not. Generally this means that `find` is less brittle (and superior). You should also be able to simplify the former to:

```
some_table_node.find("tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5)")
```

Comment: You are right about conflating it into one. I missed it.

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct - `all` doesn't wait by default but if you pass it a count, minimum, maximum, or between option it will wait

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not actually the big difference since `all` can be made to wait by passing one of the count options. The real difference between the two is that the results of `all` (and `first`) cannot be automatically reloaded.  This means if you store an element and then try to use it after the element has been replaced on the page you'll get an obsolete node error.  If you use `find` it will attempt to requery the find and reload the element that matches. A smaller benefit is that the `find` call will involve less data transfer and therefore be slightly faster.

Also note that you're queries aren't always the same.  If you have a thead with one tr in the table followed by the tbody with multiple trs, the `all` query will return the 2nd row of the tbody whereas the `find` will return the 3rd row of the tbody

```
<table id="some_table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>...</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>  <= some_table_node.all('tr')[2] will return this
    <tr>...</tr>  <= some_table_node.find('tr:nth-child(3)') will return this
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `find` involves less data transfer? It sends a `FindElements` command to the driver, probably to detect an ambiguous match.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yes `all('tr')[2]` would return info on all the rows and then pick the third entry throwing away the rest of the info.  `find('tr:nth-child(3)')` would only return on info on rows that match the selector (and raise an ambiguous match if more than one is returned)

Comment: I measured the execution time on a container with 6 items: `find_element`:31ms, `find_elements`:31ms, `find`:73ms, `all`:277ms. The native `find_element`/`find_elements` are equal since the cost is in sending a command. But `find` is twice the cost of `find_element` and `all` is 8 times. I found out that `find` and `all` are also checking the visibility by sending an extra command for each element.

Comment: @FlorentB. Ah - yes - I had forgotten about the filters that need to be applied against every element returned (visibility, and then any others with the query) - you are quite a bit better off picking the element directly with the selector instead of calling `all` with an index

Comment: @FlorentB.  Would you be willing to run the benchmark you ran again using the 'results_iterator' branch of https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the improvement is to only check the visibility for the [0..index] items. So `all` should be close to `find` for a low index, with the worst case being the last index or when `count` is called. It looks promising, I'll try it next week.

Comment: @FlorentB. Correct - it should only evaluate the filters for the minimum number of elements to get the one requested  - cleaning it up a bit currently by implementing `each`